# Looking up model name based on either VID/PID or device ID

Tags: usb, uefi

I am using a database of monitors that contains either of the following pieces of information for each monitor, either (a) 4-character [vendor ID and product ID](https://www.oshwa.org/2013/11/19/new-faq-on-usb-vendor-id-and-product-id/), or (b) a 7-character [device/hardware ID.](https://uefi.org/PNP_ACPI_Registry) I would like to use this info to obtain the monitor model name. I already know how to find the monitor manufacturer name ([this list](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids) for (a) and [this list](https://uefi.org/pnp_id_list) for (b)), but I haven't found a lookup table or method that will give me the model name, such as E2318H for a [Dell E2318H monitor](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/accessories/apd/210-ambm?mkwid=sAdFHE99y&pcrid=397043521619&pkw=dell%20e2318h&pmt=e&pdv=c&slid=&product=&pgrid=78982958538&pgrid=78982958538&ptaid=kwd-370555177567&ptaid=kwd-370555177567&VEN1=sAdFHE99y,397043521619,901q5c14135,c,,,78982958538,kwd-370555177567&VEN1=sAdFHE99y,397043521619,901q5c14135,c,,,78982958538,kwd-370555177567&VEN2=e,dell%20e2318h&VEN2=e,dell%2Be2318h&cid=312883083&cid=312883083&lid=59900160140&lid=59900160140&dgc=st&dgc=st&dgseg=bsd&dgseg=so&acd=12309152537461010&st=dell%2Be2318h&gclid=Cj0KCQiA2vjuBRCqARIsAJL5a-KQwVfJN4N8USYPc8KbVw6awPMQlYoQMsZ2GtkLQt_kIzs7otDwY64aAkcQEALw_wcB&VEN3=810305206097562101), from the product ID or hardware ID. I do not have access to the actual monitors so can't connect them to a machine and query the model name. Is there another way to look up the **human-readable model name** from the vendor ID or hardware ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question right. 
But if you are implementing from an UEFI application/driver point of view and is trying to get this information from a specific device on your target platform, you can retrieve a human-readable Product string and Manufacturer string using the EFI_USB_IO_PROTOCOL (defined by the UEFI spec) to get an USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR struct from the device. You would need to parse this struct as defined by the USB standard specification.
Hope this can be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't actually have the monitors; I only have the vendor and product ID or the hardware ID for each of them. Someone else plugged each monitor into a computer, got the IDs, and put the IDs in the database. Given the IDs, now I would like to know the model name for each of them.

Comment: Got it. Well, maybe coding a python script would help you to extract the names from these lists and put it into your database. The UEFI PNP list has an API by the URL, like https://uefi.org/PNP_ID_List?search=WDC , it could be also be useful on the script.

Comment: Good idea for the vendor name. My original question didn't make it clear that I am looking for a list or other way to find the model name from the product ID or hardware ID, such as E2318H for a Dell E2318H monitor, so I edited my question and I apologize for the confusion.